# perform trigger on a particular date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table which contains columns named as 'Date of joining' and 'Eligible for appraisal' and `monthscycle`.

in this process according to the employess 'date of joining'  and the number of `monthscycle` i have to update the 'Eligible for appraisal'.

Example:

`Name : abc ;`

`Date of joining : 07/4/2014 ;`

`Monthscycle : 12 ;`

cosider that , if todays date is 07/4/2015 it should automatically trigger the value of 
`'Eligible for appraisal'` from 0 to 1 .

is this is possible if so please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this logic of updating the `Eligible for appraisal` should be in a job that will run daily. Triggers work only when you modify information in a table, so you would have to modify the table daily. But through a task (job) you won't have to do that, you'll just run the job and inside it use and UPDATE with your logic of updating the column.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, consider running this once a day instead of every time the table is updated.  Then it is a simple update statement that looks like this:

```
UPDATE `YourTable` 
SET EligibleAppraisal = 1
WHERE CURRENT_DATE - DATE(JoinDate) >= 365;
```